# How to add SoapExtension attribute to generated web service client proxy without modifying the generated class?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, proxy, wsdl

I have created a SoapExtension class to capture the soap request and response from specific web service calls.  In order to put this SoapExtension into effect, I have to add an attribute to the method in the generated proxy client.

For example, I've added the AuditSoapCapture attribute to this method:

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://blahblah.com/webservices/AddressSearch", RequestNamespace = "http://blahblah.com/webservices/", ResponseNamespace = "http://blahblah.com/webservices/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [blahblah.TriadLite.Core.AuditSoapCapture]
    public System.Data.DataSet AddressSearch(string HouseNumber, string StreetName, string ZipCode) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("AddressSearch", new object[] {
                    HouseNumber,
                    StreetName,
                    ZipCode});
        return ((System.Data.DataSet)(results[0]));
    }
```

I am looking for a way to add this attribute to specific methods without modifying the generated client proxy, as they will get lost when we regenerate.  Can I do this in a another partial class or interface or some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use [SchemaImporterExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.advanced.schemaimporterextension.aspx) infrastructure by calling wsdl.exe with `/parameters` option (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'll need to modify the proxy code.  The other possibilities you mention will not work - a parial class will not overwrite existing functionality, and there is no way that I'm aware of getting an interface to do what you need (compounded by the fact that there is no way to even let the proxy generator know that you intend to implement an interface).

Something that I've done in the past, in a situation where you have access to the source of the webservice, is to write a little app that will parse the code (as text) in the .asmx.cs file of the webservice to extract the names of all the methods that are tagged with [WebMethod].  Then the app "fixes up" the References.cs by inserting appropriate attributes onto the proxied methods, based on some settings file or somesuch.  This works well because the naming conventions in the proxy map very neatly to the method names in the original service.

Answer (score 1):

I may just end up injecting my SoapExtension by putting it into the Web.config.  This will cause it to be run on every WS call without a client proxy method attribute.  Then, I will modify the SoapExtension to look up the called WS method name on a list, and if it is on the list, then do the rest of the SoapExtension logic.  I figure the hit on the list in this small volume application isn't going to kill performance.

Answer (score 1):

6 years ago this was posted...  So not sure if this will help anyone at this point.

I ran into something similar with a call to an old SOAP web service that had a dynamically generated proxy class that we didn't want to modify as it was auto-generated from the wsdl by the project.  In order to solve this problem here is what we did.

- The proxy class generated by wsdl.exe is a partial class. We extended this class like so to add a property with the information we wanted to access in the soapextension.  You can add as many properties as you want...

  `partial class mysoapwebservice
  {
      public string myproperty{ get; set; }
  }`
- in the web.config we registered the soap extension globaly on the project

  `<webServices>
    <soapExtensionTypes>
      <add type="MySoapExtension" priority="1" group="Low"/>
    </soapExtensionTypes>
  </webServices>`
- In the code were we created the web service object 'mysoapwebservice' we set the value of the property we needed.
- In the soapextension you can get a reference to the web service that was called as well as the values.  You can also determine the method call.

`

```
public class MySoapExtension: SoapExtension 
{
  public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
  {
    switch (message.Stage)
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                {
                    // web service client object
                    var webserviceobject= ((SoapClientMessage)message).Client;
                    // method from web service that was called
                    var calledMethod = (SoapClientMessage)message).MethodInfo;

                    // checked the client type of webserviceobject and
                    //added method / property specific logic here
                 }
         }
  }

  // other soap extension code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CriptoExtensionAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute

[CriptoExtension]
public partial class MainService{
```